# Given $S=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, ﬁnd the partition induced by the equivalence relation $R$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations, set-partition

I am currently taking discrete math and have been given the following question to answer.

Given $S=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, ﬁnd the partition induced by the equivalence relation $R$ where
$R=\{(0,0),(0,4),(1,1),(1,3),(4,5),(0,5),(5,4),(5,0),(5,5),(2,2),(3,1),(3,3),(4,0),(4,4)\}$. Explain.

For this I got $\{0,4,5\}, \{1,3\}, \{2\}$
\begin{align*}
[0],[4],[5] &= \{0,4,5\}\\
[2] &= \{2\}\\
[1],[3] &= \{1,3\}\\
\end{align*}

Does this look correct?

Comment: Looks OK, good luck with your course.

Comment: It looks correct, and it, indeed, is correct. Is there any trouble/problem, since you weren't sure about your result?

Comment: The course I am taking is online, and the material doesn't cover much.  In the past I have found good answers here.  Thanks for the quick replies.